# Bootstrap: Modal alignment issues and no transition effect upon click

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I created a simple modal, but when I click the button the modal appears at the very top of the page and there is no fade in animation when the modal appears. There is no background behind the modal that covers the entire web application as well.  I set the correct classes, but still no luck.

Here is my button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">
    Add Function
</button>
```

The modal itself:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            <h1>Lab 6</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #e0e9f5">
                            <h2 class="panel-title">Employee Function - Add</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <div class="well">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                                        <h5>
                                            <span style="color: red">* </span>Code:
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                                        <h5>
                                            <span style="color: red">* </span>Description:
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                                        <h5>Legacy Function Code:</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                                        <h5>Active?</h5>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-1">

                                        <input type="radio">
                                        <h5>Yes</h5>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-2">

                                        <input type="radio">
                                        <h5>No</h5>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6" align="right">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6" align="left">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example is what I would like to achieve: 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: could you post the <head> contents of your HTML file?

Comment: The main index file contains all the scripts and hrefs within the head for the web app. I have a side bar navigation and each page is structured the within a row class and a col-md-12 class.  So this page is structured like that.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have simply forgotten to add boostrap CSS + JS or jQuery. Below is a code snippet, with your exact code, but with boostrap CSS + JS and jQuery included. Note that jQuery must be before the boostrap JS link, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

All of that should go in the `<head>` tag (or at the bottom of the `<body>` tag)

```html
<!-- Stuff for the <head> tag -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- end <head> tag -->
<!-- Stuff for the <body> -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">
    Add Function
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h1>Lab 6</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #e0e9f5">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Employee Function - Add</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="well">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                      <h5>
                        <span style="color: red">* </span>Code:
                      </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <br />

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                      <h5>
                        <span style="color: red">* </span>Description:
                      </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <br />

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                      <h5>Legacy Function Code:</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <br />

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
                      <h5>Active?</h5>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-1">

                      <input type="radio">
                      <h5>Yes</h5>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">

                      <input type="radio">
                      <h5>No</h5>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <br />

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" align="right">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" align="left">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

P.S. The result looks better when you expand the snippet before running it, because otherwise the output has a small width which messes things up (which could be an issue on small devices)

Comment: The index file contains this code already, but in my case the order of top to bottom was bootstrap.min.css > jquery.min.js > bootstrap.min.js.  I tried the order you recommeded but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: As i explained in a comment above, the index file contains all the styles and herfs.  I have a side bar navigaiton and each page is laid out using the roll class and split up using the col-md-12 class.

Comment: ahh that did help in terms of the fade in animation and a bg for the web app when the modal appears.  Is there a way for me to increase the size of the modal and adjust it to the center of the page?

Comment: @Adrew Do you mean the modal or the button? Because the modal is already in the center of the page...

Comment: One more question.  I have similar scripts and stylesheets declared in the index.html but without the integrity and crossorigin declaration.
Do i need to declare this within the index and your code snippet within the html page for the modal? i declared your code snippet within the index and had issues.

Comment: The modal.  I apologize it is centered, but I mean to align it vertically to the middle of the page.  Right now it is aligned vertically to the top of the page.

Comment: Oh, ok. The key word there was 'vertically'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147739/discussion-between-james-douglas-and-adrew).